# Ocaml won't let me name my List

Tags: ocaml

the code :

```
open Hashtbl;;

type 'a option = None | Some of 'a;;

let ht = create 0;;

let rec charCount fd =
  let x = 
    try Some (input_char fd)
    with End_of_file -> None
  in
  match x with
  | Some c -> 
    let v = 
      try find ht c
      with Not_found -> 0
    in
    replace ht c (v+1);
    charCount fd
  | None -> ();;

let loadHisto fn = 
  let fd = open_in fn in 
    charCount fd;;

let rec printList l = match l with
  | [] -> print_newline ()
  | h::t -> print_char h; print_string " "; printList t;;

let hashtbl_keys h = Hashtbl.fold (fun key _ l -> key :: l) h [];;
let compare_function a b = compare (find ht b) (find ht a);;
let akeys = List.sort compare_function (hashtbl_keys ht);;

printList (List.sort compare_function (hashtbl_keys ht));;
printList akeys;;
```

and the result :

```
ocaml histo.ml
  e t s u a i n p j (*here is the first printList*)
(*and here should be the second one, but there is only a blank*)
```

Here is the problem : 
I sorted a list, and tried to display it's content but as you can see, it doesn't seem like I can give a name to my resulting List

Edit : 
I don't think it's a buffer problem because even if I only print akeys, there is nothing

Edit : I added the code asked for below
And ht is a hashtbl, and it contains what it should contain (I checked this)

Comment: What's the definition of `printList` ?  Most likely you need to flush the output buffer.

Comment: Also, how do you know it's the first statement which prints correctly? ;), try printing your variable twice, to check that indeed it doesn't get printed.

Comment: (I have edited the question) And : I've tried PrintList in many combinasion between akeys and it's supposed value. The result is always the same : nothing for akeys

Comment: I guess you'll have to provide more code (`hashtbl_keys`, `compare_function`) otherwise it won't be possible to help you. Have you heard of [sscce](http://sscce.org)?

Comment: edited with all functions used (testfile is a simple text file)

Comment: Hmm, I added a line to actually load some data in the hashtable, and it works for me..

Comment: There is one crucial thing that it is still missing in your code: when are you calling `loadHisto` over the actual test file? I suspect that this between the definition of `akeys` and the first `printList`. In that case, `akeys` is defined using an empty hash table, hence is an empty list.